# Regex going too far, need to limit it

Tags: regex

I have the following data set:

```
C:\folder1\log.txt
C:\folder1\folder2\log.txt
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\log.txt
```

I am trying to use regex to match log.txt files which may appear in the list at many levels of depth (folders, which in turn will have different names).

So assuming I want to match all the files log.txt that are "two-folders deep", I try the following regex but it is not working for me.

```
(.*\\){0,2}log\.txt
```

It is not working specifically because it matches every line, not just the one that is "two-folders deep".

How can I limit this to work as expected? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative character set instead of `.`, so that you can match any character but a backslash, and make sure to anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string:

```
^([^\\]*\\){0,2}log\.txt
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q9JBcl/1

Comment: Thanks CertainPerformance! In your regex, if I change the number to 0,4 (for example), it is now capturing all the lines again. My goal is that when I change that number it would match exactly the level of depth accordingly. What are your thoughts?

Comment: If you want to match lines that only have a depth *up to* 2 (or 4), or whatever, then use that method, `{0,2}` or `{0,4}`, or whichever you want. If you want to match lines that only have a depth of *exactly* some amount, then just put that number in, eg `{3}`

Comment: Absolutely correct! Thanks for the clarification. I am somewhat new to regex and I am working on it.